# Use a palette for hue in Seaborn Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, hue

I want to use my own colour palette for the hue. I am following the documentation but for some reason, I can't get it right.

**Here is my code**:

```
%matplotlib inline
colors = ["#ff4c8b", "#00d8d5",'#f7f7f7'] 


sns.set_style(rc={'axes.facecolor':'black','figure.facecolor':'black','axes.grid' : False})
s=sns.lineplot(data=data, x="timestamp", y="close.quote",palette=sns.set_palette(sns.color_palette(colors)), hue='contract_ticker_symbol')
```

Instead of using the three colours I defined, it uses the default hue palette.Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: Wouldn't it work with just `palette=colors`?

Comment: it gives this error : 
ValueError: The palette list has the wrong number of colors.

Comment: JohanC has the correct approach, but your error is because you have 11 groups, but are only supplying 3 colors. For `palette` to work you need to supply an equal number of colors to the number of unique values in your data listed under hue (in this case `data["contract_ticker_symbol"]`